# Shaking notification bar

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, notification-bar

On an Asus Transformer Prime, my notification bar at the bottom of the screen will randomly start dancing up and down, and sometimes just scramble then go normal. When it does either one of these behaviours, I need to restart my Android to get it to stop. When it scrambles, the rest of the screen is fine, and I can click on areas of the bar that are messed up as if it wasn't, and access their functions (i.e. Back, Home, etc)

Comment: I had similar problems with a Nook Color. Switching off the screen and cleaning helped most of the time.

Comment: @ce4 Cleaning what? The screen? A connector?

Comment: yeah, the screen. forgot an 'it' before helped

Comment: I'll give that a try tonight and see if I notice any change

Comment: I got my Nook calm by sticking a protection layer onto the screen. It has an oversensitive touch screen

Comment: @ce4 If that's the case, I think Asus should have provided one... But why the shaking or the random disappearing act?

Comment: maybe try to have one of these 'multitouch test' apps open when it happens next time. You could then see if its the touch digitizer that's causing this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4068/discussion-between-luke-and-ce4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asus released an update, and it's been 2 weeks since it happened